# Maze generator for Dungeons and Dragons

Tags: python

Hello everyone I was told to post this here instead of StackOverFlow.

I am using PyAutoGUI currently as this was the best tools I could manage to find to use a piece of software that has no native Python function. I am using the mouse and keyboard control to design maps for Dungeons and Dragons using the software Dungeon Painter Studio. It is working as intended and I have figured out a way to actually use my script to create maps on it however, since PyAutoGUI is based on mouse location and pixels it has been quite a manual process.

EDIT:

Here is a picture of the software with nothing in it just opened up:
[image]

Here is a picture after the code has been ran:
[image]

My reason for creating this script is so that I can eventually randomize it to create a random generated map for my D&D campaign that is somewhat original compared to just taking a map off the internet.

I am inputting a starting location for the mouse and have it click and moved based on relative location to that starting position. Here is a piece of what it currently looks like:

```
#Switch to dps, maximize window, select the tile hotkey

pyautogui.keyDown('altleft'); pyautogui.press('tab'); pyautogui.keyUp('altleft')
fw = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
fw.maximize()
pyautogui.keyDown('enter')

#Select the background tile

pyautogui.click('dirt_k.png')

#Create background

pyautogui.moveTo(9,189) 
pyautogui.mouseDown(9,189)
pyautogui.moveTo(748,808)
pyautogui.mouseUp(252,436)

#Select the dugeon tile

pyautogui.click('dirt_d.png')

#Create dungeon floor

pyautogui.moveTo(329,807)
pyautogui.mouseDown(329,807)
pyautogui.moveRel(100,-75)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(-25,0)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(-50,-50)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(-100,0)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(250,-125)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(0,100)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(50,25)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(0,100)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(100,-125)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(0,0)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(-25,-50)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(-75,0)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(175,-100)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(-25,-50)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

pyautogui.moveRel(25,0)
pyautogui.mouseDown()
pyautogui.moveRel(-225,-125)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

It basically continues on like that for hundreds of lines to create a sample map. I was just seeing if anyone else is familiar enough with PyAutoGUI (or any other tools) that would help automated this process a bit more.

I have the amount of pixels per square which is roughly 25px so it isn't too hard to calculate. Moving right is +25 left is -25 down is +25 up is -25. So using those measurements I have been able to calculate relative location where the mouse starts and move it around from there.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: We are missing some information here. Can you include a screenshot of the program you're scripting, and explain why you're scripting it (instead of doing it once by hand?)

Comment: Just added an edit with some screenshots so you can see it. The reason I am running this and want to optimize it is so that eventually I can randomly generate these maps to add to my D&D game.

Answer (score 1):

> My reason for creating this script is so that I can eventually randomize it to create a random generated map for my D&D campaign that is somewhat original compared to just taking a map off the internet.

Given that you want to eventually make a random map, your current approach won't work. You're just using hardcoded values, and there is no way to "randomize" it without fundamentally re-writing it.

- The first change I would recommend is separate the data out. This makes the program shorter, clearer, and easier to change to add something like randomness

```
#Create dungeon floor
pyautogui.moveTo(329,807)
pyautogui.mouseDown(329,807)
pyautogui.moveRel(100,-75)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

lines = [
    ((-25, 0), (-50, 50)),
    ((-100,0), (250,-125))
    ((0,100), (50,25)),
    ((0,100), (100,-125)),
    ((0,0), (-25,-50)),
    ((-75,0), (175,-100)),
    ((0,0), (-25,-50)),
    ((25,0), (-225,-125)),
]

for down, up in lines:
    pyautogui.moveRel(*down)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    pyautogui.moveRel(*up)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

- Work in absolute coordinates, not relative ones. It will make things easier for random dungeons.
- Add comments. Does a particular mouse movement draw a room? Does it draw a line bordering a room? I have literally no idea. In this case, move movement is so opaque it will be useful for you as well, not just other readers.
- As a warning, the whole idea of scripting a dungeon generation program may not be worth it. What happens if you want a map that's bigger than your screen resolution? If you just output your own image directly, it will be easier than scripting in some ways.

Comment: Yes this is perfect and what I was looking for something along these lines (pun intended)! In a all seriousness though I do recognize the limitations of working with a limited amount of screen space right now and was heading in the direction you just explained. Adding the lines like that should really help. As for the limited map spacing, I was planning on just creating multiple that could possibly connected if I wrote in some kind of connection point to be in that would carry over into the next map. This is a great start for me though and I really do appreciate the time you took to answer